# PHP - Outputting specific content from an array

Tags: php, arrays

How do I output the [Comment][title]s one after another in this array?

```
Array
(  
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [user_id] => 121
                    [title] => On Gwoo the Kungwoo
                    [body] => The Kungwooness is not so Gwooish
                    [created] => 2006-05-01 10:31:01
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [user_id] => 121
                    [title] => More on Gwoo
                    [body] => But what of the ‘Nut?
                    [created] => 2006-05-01 10:41:01
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: cakephp perchance? looks like one of its excuses for an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that won't work, a ) should be a ]

```
foreach ($foo['Comment'] as $comment) {
  echo $comment['title'];
}
```

in templates try to use this, designers like this better:

```
foreach($foo['Comment'] as $comment):
      echo $comment['title'];
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 4):

Where `$foo` is the array, do:

```
foreach ($foo['Comment'] as $comment) {
    echo $comment['title'];
}
```